# "slyr-master" plugin for QGIS doesn't work due to "missing meta data"

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I downloaded the "slyr" plugin from GitHub which should be able to convert .style data into QGIS. According to the README file, I'm just supposed to add the "slyr" folder to the Python -> Plugin folder and activated it in QGIS.

When I go to the QGIS Plugin extentions the plugin appears but I get the error message "This plugin is defect. Metadata is missing". However, there is a metadata.txt file inside the "slyr" folder.

Does anyone have any ideas what the problem might be and how to solve it?

I'm using QGIS 3.4.6.

Comment: I think that is better create a issue https://github.com/nyalldawson/slyr/issues

Comment: More info about an open source license release in June 2020, more info at : https://north-road.com/slyr/, and many kudos for @ndawson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works in QGIS 3.10. It will most likely also work in 3.4.6 since it says

> "SLYR also functions as a QGIS plugin (for QGIS >= 3.2)"

on the SLYR homepage on github.

After downloading slyr-master.zip from https://github.com/nyalldawson/slyr, unzip it and open the slyr-master folder. Here you'll find another slyr-folder. Copy and paste only this folder into C:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins.

Source: [image: Source: slyr-master\slyr-folder]
Destination: [image: Destination: QGIS-plugin folder]

In QGIS, go to Plugins–Manage and Install Plugins, In the Installed tab SLYR will be listed. Turn it on (checked).

[image]

Download the mdbtools (mdbtools-win-master.zip) mentioned in https://github.com/nyalldawson/slyr

> "All tools require the command line mdbtools for handling the .style
>   database files. Binaries of these can be downloaded from
>   https://github.com/lsgunth/mdbtools-win, and they should be extracted
>   and available in the Windows path."

Unzip mdbtools-win-master.zip and copy the filepath to the unzipped folder mdbtools-win-master.

In QGIS, open Settings–Options–Processing. Click on Providers and SLYR and paste in the mdbtools-filepath in the Location-field. Click OK.

[image: Paste in the filepath for the mdbtools]

Now, you're ready to use SLYR.
Open the ToolBox (Processing–Toolbox or just press Ctrl-Alt-T). At the bottom you'll find SLYR, open SLYR–Style databases and choose the preferred tool, e.g. "Convert ESRI style to QGIS XML".

[image: SLYR-tools]

Choose the ArcGIS style-file to be converted. Click Run.

[image]

Then go to Settings–Style manager and import the XML-file just created. Click Import/Export and navigate to the XML-file. You may add additional tags. Click Select all (or just select the symbols you want) followed by Import.

[image: Import XML]

In the Tags-list, choose one of the tags given previously (e.g. arcgis or forestry). The forestry styles appears.
[image: Show the symbols by tag]

Now I have access to all the styles from Layer styling-panel. The symbols available will change according to the geometry of the layer. E.g. choose the arcgis style from the list in the Style manager-list for a point file:

[image]